# Laravel nested loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops, nested-loops

I'm receiving an error trying to do a nested loop in a blade @foreach

This is what I've tried, yeam im using 2 `key` on it.. is there any way to relation it?

here is my controller code

```
$product = Product::where($where)->get();
        foreach($product as $key=>$value){
            if($value->SupplierID){
                $product[$key]['SupplierName'] = Company::find($value->SupplierID)->CompanyName;
            }else{
                $product[$key]['SupplierName'] = '-';
            }

            $product[$key]['ProductName'] = $value->getProdNameOne()->ProductName;

        }

        if(!empty(Auth::user())){
            $userid = Auth::user()->id;

            $companyfromusers = Companypersonstruct::where('user_id','=',$userid)->first();

            if(!empty($companyfromusers->user_id)){
                $companyrelationstruct = CompanyRelationStruct::where('FromCompanyID','=',$companyfromusers->CompanyID)->get();

                if(!empty($companyrelationstruct)){
                    foreach($companyrelationstruct as $key=>$crs){
                        $relatedcompany[] = Company::where('id','=',$crs->ToCompanyID)->get();
                    }
                } else {
                    $relatedcompany = '-';
                }
            } else {
                $relatedcompany = '-';
            }
        }
```

and this is my view code

```
@foreach ($product as $key=>$products)
        <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $products->ProductNumber }}</th>
        <td><a href="/detailproduct/{{ $products->id }}" target="_blank"> {{ $products->ProductName }}</a></td>
    @if(\Auth::user())
      @foreach($relatedcompany[$key] as $keychild=>$valchild)
        <td>{{ $valchild->CompanyName }}</td>
      @endforeach
        <td>{{ $products->UnitCustPrice }}</td>
    @endif
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

This is the error that I'm receiving:

> Undefined offset: 2

Comment: That's because $relatedcompany[2] doesn't exists, debug the data that you're sending in the controller

Comment: then, what i have to do?

Comment: I couldn't quite understand the logic of your code. It seems to me that there is no logical relation between your `$products` array and your `$relatedcompany` array. The `$relatedcompany` array seems to be only relevant to the login user. If so, why do you want to loop through the `$relatedcompany` in your `$product` array loop?

Comment: ya, theres no relation between `products` and `relatedcompany`. but i want to show `relatedcompany` for each `product`..

Comment: `relatedcompany` only have relation with `user`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are multiple problems that can be addressed.

```php
$product = Product::where($where)->get();
foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->SupplierID) {
        $product[$key]['SupplierName'] = Company::find($value->SupplierID)->CompanyName;
    } else {
        $product[$key]['SupplierName'] = '-';
    }
    $product[$key]['ProductName'] = $value->getProdNameOne()->ProductName;
}

$relatedcompany = false;
if (!empty(Auth::user())) {
    $userid = Auth::user()->id;

    $companyfromusers = Companypersonstruct::where('user_id', '=', $userid)->first();
    $relatedcompany = array();

    if (!empty($companyfromusers->user_id)) {
        $companyrelationstruct = CompanyRelationStruct::where('FromCompanyID', '=', $companyfromusers->CompanyID)->get();
        if (!empty($companyrelationstruct)) {
            foreach ($companyrelationstruct as $crs) {
                $relatedcompany[] = Company::find($crs->ToCompanyID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Supposed you have passed the variables correctly, this is the view code that can work with `$product` and `$relatedcompany` above.

```
@foreach ($product as $key=>$products)
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $products->ProductNumber }}</th>
    <td><a href="/detailproduct/{{ $products->id }}" target="_blank"> {{ $products->ProductName }}</a></td>
    @if ($relatedcompany !== false)
        @forelse ($relatedcompany as $company)
          @if ($company)
            <td>{{ $company->CompanyName }}</td>
          @endif
        @empty
          <td>-</td>
        @endforelse
      <td>{{ $products->UnitCustPrice }}</td>
    @endif
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: then how to avoid using key?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid using key"? You current code suggested you have 2 separated arrays: `$product` and `$relatedcompany`. And there is nothing co-relating the 2 except for the `$key`. If this is not the case, there is a logically error in your code. And if that's so, you have to provide more information or code for us to understand your problem.

Comment: code above give me `Property [CompanyName] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: Updated. Please try again. (BTW, you should be able to fix this by understanding what is a collection)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
@foreach ($product as $key=>$products)
        <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $products->ProductNumber }}</th>
        <td><a href="/detailproduct/{{ $products->id }}" target="_blank"> {{ $products->ProductName }}</a></td>
    @if(\Auth::user())
      @if(isset($relatedcompany[$key]))
        @foreach($relatedcompany[$key] as $keychild=>$valchild)
          <td>{{ $valchild->CompanyName }}</td>
        @endforeach
      @endif
        <td>{{ $products->UnitCustPrice }}</td>
    @endif
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```